# gradle dependency for RESTful jersey

Tags: rest, gradle, jersey, dependencies

Adding RESTful support to an existing web app using jersey:

```
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.25.1'
```

has the following huge dependencies

```
\--- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.25.1
     +--- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1
     |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
     |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1
     |    |    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
     |    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.25.1
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    |    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     |    |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.5.0-b32 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
     |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:1.0.1
     |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.25.1
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25.1
     |    |    |    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.5.0-b32 (*)
     |    |    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:2.25.1
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.5.0-b32 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:1.0.1
     |    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
     |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.5.0-b32 (*)
     |    |    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
     |    \--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
     +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
     +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.25.1 (*)
     \--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
```

Too much. I expected several jars only. The web app is running within tomcat.
Do I need to include the jersey container? What is minimum dependencies for adding jersey to an existing web app?

Comment: Yes. You need all of this.

Answer (score 0):

jersey-container-servlet is the minimum for the server API if you're pulling it in with Maven. I've tried it without maven in the past and ended up having to hunt down almost all of those jars manually. Stick with maven.